# C# validate string input to date with culture info

Tags: c#, .net, validation, datetime

I am reading string inputs from an excel sheet and I want to check if the string is a valid date.

To do so, I have:

```
    public static bool IsValidDate(string DateStr)
    {
        DateStr = DateStr.Trim();
        DateTime tempDate = new DateTime().Date;

        return DateTime.TryParse(DateStr, out tempDate);
    }
```

The problem in here is that in case that string is **13/12/2021** it will return **false(not valid)** because set 13 as month and 12 as day.

What is the proper approach to manipulate string format and do a right check inside the same function?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: OT you do not need to initialize that `tempDate` before using it as an `out` parameter. A method receiving an out parameter (like `TryParse`) must treat it as uninitialized on entry and must definitely have assigned a value on exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static bool IsValidDate(string DateStr)
{
    DateStr = DateStr.Trim();
    DateTime tempDate = new DateTime().Date;

    return DateTime.TryParse(DateStr, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the method to take a `CultureInfo`/`DateTimeFormatInfo` that uses a format string which starts with the days instead of the month. You could use this:

```
public static bool IsValidDate(string dateStr, out DateTime theParsedDateTime, IFormatProvider fp = null)
{
    if (fp == null)
        fp = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;
    return DateTime.TryParse(dateStr.Trim(), fp, DateTimeStyles.None, out theParsedDateTime);
}
```

Now you can call this method in this way, i have used german `CultureInfo` because that is a working example. Note that `InvariantInfo` doesn't work because it starts with months:

```
bool valid = IsValidDate("13/12/2021", out DateTime parsedDate, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a CultureInfo with CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture.
And then parse the string using the specific culture.

Just see the example [under](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score -2):

This works for me.

```
public static bool IsValidDate(string DateStr)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(DateStr, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
}
```